# variable string conversion with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to convert a variable string depending on the context with sed.

```
string="GAGGTGGGTGGGGAGC"
echo $string | sed -r 's/G+([AT])/A+\1/g'
```

The result is: `A+AA+TA+TA+AGC`. But I expect: `AAAATAAATAAAAAGC`

In other words, I would like to substitute an unknown stretch of Gs into As only if they are followed by a A or T. How can we recover the number of Gs of the matched patterns to reuse it in the substitution pattern?

Comment: With `perl`, you can use a regex like `s/G(?=G*[AT])/A/g`. sed does not support lookarounds, unfortunately.

Comment: Works great ! Thanks. For the records the command line to use is:`echo $string | perl -pe 's/G(?=G*[AT])/A/g' `

Comment: Please note that in this case it would be trivial to build a small state machine to do the parsing.  If you have a significant amount of data to process and will do it regularly, the performance might be worth the extra effort.  Also, if you have many strings to process, be sure to pipe them to `sed` as a stream, and not call `sed` once for every string to process, which will slow things down dramatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sed, using backreference and the `t`(test) command to loop at the beginning of the command for further replacement if substitution succeed:

```
$ sed ':a;s/G\([AT]\)\(.*\)/A\1\2/;ta;' <<< "GAGGTGGGTGGGGAGC"
AAAATAAATAAAAAGC
```

How it works:

- `:a`: `a` label for upcoming loop
- `s`: substitute command
- `G\([AT]\)`: search for `G` followed by `A` or `T`. Second letter is captured and will be used in replacement string using backreference
- `\(.*\)`: captures remaining characters
- `A\1\2`: replace with `A` followed by previously captured strings(`A` or `T` and remaining characters)
- `ta`: if previous substitution succeed, go to label `:a`(beginning) of the script to check for further replacements

Comment: It works well, but could you explain the logic behind?

Comment: @retrogenomics I added some explanations.